# Wordpress Links

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I want some Wordpress hyperlinks to be like this:

Instead of:
(url)travel/Paris
(url)hotels/Venice

I want them to be just (url)Paris, or (url)Venice, without the category in front of them.

Thing is, that even if I get rid of the category/title pattern, after I click on the (url)Paris link, it takes me to (url)travel/Paris.

So what's happening here is that I am successfully creating a link called (url)Paris, or a link called (url)Venice, but once I click on it, I get re-directed to the link I don't want (in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

To set default permalink settings, go to your "Permalink" page on the "Settings" tab of your Wordpress admin panel or you can go directly to `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` address.

On this page there is a lot of options to do whatever you want. For your problem, you should select "Postname" option. You can create custom URLs using https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks Wordpress documantation.